# Android studio activity XML can't get the layout weights to align properly

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I am really battling to understand how to get the linear layouts to take on the correct proportions within my xml activity.

Below is my code. There are essentially 3 layers (labelled layer one, layer two and layer three). I want them to align vertically so that that layer 1 takes up about the top 10% of the screen, later 2 takes up the next 10% of the screen and then layer 3 takes up the remaining 80% of the screen.

With the code below, the widgets within the top 2 layers are being squashed and therefore I cant see the full widgets. I'm sure it's got to do with the way I am using layout-weights but I'm just not sure how to fix it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layTopLevel"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:orientation="vertical">





    <!--layer one-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layerOne"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/layoutName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txtMyPlaceName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/myPlaceName" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/etMyPlaceName"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="Enter name here"
                        android:singleLine="true" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>



        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/layoutType"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/customborder"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtMyPlaceType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:text="@string/myPlaceType" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spnType"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style = "@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>












    <!--Layer Two-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layerTwo"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.333">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="addSightingToDb"
                    android:text="@string/addSighting" />

            </RelativeLayout>



            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.333">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnClearLast"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="addSightingToDb"
                    android:text="@string/addSighting" />

            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.334">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btnClearAll"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:onClick="addSightingToDb"
                    android:text="@string/addSighting" />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>












    <!--Layer three-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layerThree"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="8">


        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>




<!--<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
    <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
    <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
    <!--xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"-->
    <!--android:layout_marginTop="10dp"-->
    <!--android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"-->
    <!--android:orientation="horizontal">-->



        <!--<LinearLayout-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
            <!--android:orientation="vertical">-->


                <!--<LinearLayout-->
                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                    <!--android:layout_height="fill_parent"-->
                    <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                    <!--android:background="@drawable/customborder"-->
                    <!--android:orientation="vertical" >-->


                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;first row&ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--<LinearLayout-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_weight="0.5"-->
                        <!--android:background="@drawable/customborder"-->
                        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"-->
                        <!--android:orientation="horizontal" >-->

                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
                            <!--android:layout_weight="0.50">-->

                            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                                <!--android:background="@drawable/customborder"-->
                                <!--android:orientation="vertical" >-->

                                <!--<TextView-->
                                    <!--android:id="@+id/txtMyPlaceName"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:text="@string/myPlaceName" />-->

                                <!--<EditText-->
                                    <!--android:id="@+id/etMyPlaceName"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:singleLine="true" />-->

                            <!--</LinearLayout>-->

                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
                            <!--android:layout_weight="0.50">-->

                            <!--<LinearLayout-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_weight="1"-->
                                <!--android:background="@drawable/customborder"-->
                                <!--android:orientation="vertical" >-->

                                <!--<TextView-->
                                    <!--android:id="@+id/txtMyPlaceType"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:text="@string/myPlaceType" />-->

                                <!--<Spinner-->
                                    <!--android:id="@+id/spnSeenHeard"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                    <!--style = "@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"-->
                                    <!--/>-->

                            <!--</LinearLayout>-->

                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

                    <!--</LinearLayout>-->



                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;button row&ndash;&gt;-->

                    <!--<LinearLayout-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_weight="0.50"-->
                        <!--android:background="@drawable/customborder"-->
                        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"-->
                        <!--android:orientation="horizontal" >-->


                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
                            <!--android:layout_weight="0.34">-->

                            <!--<Button-->
                                <!--android:id="@+id/btnAdd"-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:gravity="left|center_vertical"-->
                                <!--android:onClick="addSightingToDb"-->
                                <!--android:text="@string/addSighting" />-->

                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->


                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
                            <!--android:layout_weight="0.33">-->

                            <!--<Button-->
                                <!--android:id="@+id/btnClearLast"-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:gravity="left|center_vertical"-->
                                <!--android:onClick="addSightingToDb"-->
                                <!--android:text="@string/addSighting" />-->

                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                            <!--android:gravity="center_vertical"-->
                            <!--android:layout_weight="0.33">-->

                            <!--<Button-->
                                <!--android:id="@+id/btnClearAll"-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                                <!--android:gravity="left|center_vertical"-->
                                <!--android:onClick="addSightingToDb"-->
                                <!--android:text="@string/addSighting" />-->

                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->

                    <!--</LinearLayout>-->




                    <!--&lt;!&ndash;Map row&ndash;&gt;-->
                    <!--<LinearLayout-->
                        <!--android:id="@+id/layout_map"-->
                        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
                        <!--android:layout_weight="0.50"-->
                        <!--android:background="@drawable/customborder"-->
                        <!--android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"-->
                        <!--android:orientation="horizontal" >-->

                        <!--<RelativeLayout-->
                            <!--android:id="@+id/map_layout"-->
                            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
                            <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->


                            <!--<fragment-->
                                <!--android:id="@+id/map"-->
                                <!--android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"-->
                                <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
                                <!--android:layout_height="match_parent"-->
                                <!--android:layout_alignParentStart="true"-->
                                <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />-->



                        <!--</RelativeLayout>-->




                    <!--</LinearLayout>-->




                <!--</LinearLayout>-->


    <!--</LinearLayout>-->




<!--</LinearLayout>-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**When you use weights on a view, you are limiting the height of the view.**

*If the required height of the view exceeds the height assigned to it by the                 android:layout_weight attribute, its child views will be squashed to respect the layout_weight attribute.*

Remove layout_weight attribute on all layers.

Set layer-one height to wrap_content

Set layer-two height to wrap_content

set layer-three height to match_parent.